# Skipping every other element in a DolphinDB array

Tags: dolphindb

I am trying to get an array containing every other element in my original array `a`. In python, I can do this with `a[::2]`. I wonder in what way I can do this simply and fast in DolphinDB.

I can write a `for` loop and repeatedly `append!` the every other element. But I don't think it's an elegant solution.

```
a = 1..10
result = []
skip = false
for (element in a) {
    if (!skip)
        result.append!(element)
    skip = !skip
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create an index vector to retrieve every other element of the original vector.

```
a[0..((a.size() - 1)/2) * 2]
```